# Tensorflow crashes on sess.run() with no logs in python console

Tags: tensorflow

I tried to implement style transfer using vgg-19 model. I loaded weights through existing keras model of vgg-19 using tensorflow as backend. First I tried it on my notebook and it ran fine though very slow on tf 0.11.0. Then I switched to my AWS instance with gpus, which has version 0.12.1, and tried the very same script: it produces no errors in jupyter notebook, but instead freezes the kernel and forces it to restart when I try to compute an output of a specific layer, except the input of the first layer. I installed gpu version of 0.11.0 - the same problem, though both versions passed test of matrix multiplication.

I've also tried running on 0.12.1 someone's script using vgg-16 written for 0.11.0 and session crashed because of error in layer dimensions, though it ran fine on 0.11.0 on cpu. GPU version of tf 0.11.0 - same freeze and restart.

Are there any logs written by tensorflow except for those in python console? I have not managed to find any mentions about them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed. The cudnn version mismatched the tensorflow version - it gave the error output only to python console, not to the jupyter notebook